# factors sum to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, factoring

If I have factors of linear operators say

$$(a_1 + A)(a_2 + A)(a_3 + A)\cdots(a_n + A) = 0$$

$A$ being an linear operator(i guess it really doesn't matter its operator or not) why

$$\sum_{n}  \frac{X_n(A)}{X_n(a_n)} = 1$$

$X$ function is the quotient function, for example:

$$X_2(A) = (a_1 + A)(a_3 + A)\cdots(a_n + A)$$

a numerical example is $$(1+A)(1-A)=0$$

then

$$\frac{X_1(A)}{X_1(a_1)} +\frac{X_2(A)}{X_2(a_2)} =
  \frac{1+A}{2} +\frac{1-A}{2} = 1$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the sum is 1

Comment: I think more clarification is needed. Also why in your numerical example do you have a term with $-A$ in it when in your generalized scenario you only have $+A$?

Comment: Just time -1 it will be same as above